# undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass ajax & multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've tried to find an answer for this but with no luck.

The index of my page is set to model channels/index. The channels/index renders a partial channels/_index.

Everything works fine so far. When I added a second model which works very similar to my first model, I basically copied everything and changed all parameters. The index of my Second model "Apply" then has to be rendered n the Channels/index. But the model apply also has a partial _index which is rendered on the applies/index.

This produces the following error:
**undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass**

```
<%= @applies.each do |apply| %>
    <h5><%= link_to apply.name, apply_path(apply), remote: true %><h5>

<% end %>
```

**Here is my applies/index**

```
<%= link_to "Apply for membership", new_apply_path, remote: true %>

<%= render :partial => "applies/index" %>
```

**applies/_index**

```
<%= @applies.each do |apply| %>
    <h5><%= link_to apply.name, apply_path(apply), remote: true %><h5>

<% end %>
```

**Channels/index**

```
<%= render "applies/index" %>

<%= link_to "Create new Channel", new_channel_path, remote: true %>

      <div class="channel-index"> 
     <%= render "index" %>
    </div>
```

**Channels/_index**

```
<% @channels.each do |channel| %>
    <h5><%= link_to channel.name, channel_path(channel), remote: true %><h5>

<% end %>
```

**Channels Controller**

```
class ChannelsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @channels = Channel.all.order("created_at ASC")
  end

  def show
    @channel = Channel.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @channel = Channel.new
  end

  def create 
    @channel = Channel.create(channel_params)
    @channels = Channel.all


  end

  def edit
    @channel = Channel.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @channel.update_attributes(channel_params)
    @channels = Channel.all
    @channel = Channel.find(params[:id])


  end

  def delete
    @channel = Channel.find(params[:channel_id])
  end

  def destroy
    @channel = Channel.find(params[:id])
    @channels = Channel.all
    @channel.destroy

  end

private
  def channel_params
    params.require(:channel).permit(:name, :description)
  end

end
```

**Applies Controller**

```
class AppliesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @applies = Apply.all.order("created_at ASC")
  end

  def show
    @apply = Apply.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @apply = Apply.new
  end

  def create 
    @apply = Apply.create(apply_params)
    @applies = Apply.all


  end

  def edit
    @apply = Apply.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @apply.update_attributes(apply_params)
    @applies = Apply.all
    @apply = Apply.find(params[:id])


  end

  def delete
    @apply = Apply.find(params[:apply_id])
  end

  def destroy
    @apply = Apply.find(params[:id])
    @applies = Apply.all
    @apply.destroy

  end

private
  def apply_params
    params.require(:apply).permit(:name, :email, :website)
  end

end
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Why do I get the NoMethodError...

Comment: BTW, you almost never want to combine `<%= ... %>` with `each`, `<%= @applies.each do |apply| %>` should be `<% @applies.each do |apply| %>` or you'll get an unexpected stringified array in your output.

Comment: Yeah - I know, it was a mistake, lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to Channels Controller and Applies Controller

```
  def index
    @channels = Channel.all.order("created_at ASC")
    @applies = Apply.all.order("created_at ASC")
  end
```